# periodicity question for $2^n \bmod 10^d$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to find a cleaner formula for various `powers-of-10` residuals for `any power of 2`

e.g.

```
   2^x    last 14-digits                              delta
-----------------------------------------------------------
    24 =        16777216 = #srand1653951976.896725# =    24
 62524 = 807129 76777216 = #srand1653951979.478611# = 62500
125024 = 614259 36777216 = #srand1653951986.942676# = 62500

187524 = 421388 96777216 = #srand1653951999.242219# = 62500
250024 = 228518 56777216 = #srand1653952016.367700# = 62500
312524 =  35648 16777216 = #srand1653952038.319777# = 62500 <—— finally repeated last-8
```

Or more generally, is the following extrapolation accurate ?

```
                      4 -> 5^(  1-1 ) * 4 -> 2ⁿ mod 10^ 1  cyclic period 
                     20 -> 5^(  2-1 ) * 4 -> 2ⁿ mod 10^ 2  cyclic period 
                    100 -> 5^(  3-1 ) * 4 -> 2ⁿ mod 10^ 3  cyclic period 
                    500 -> 5^(  4-1 ) * 4 -> 2ⁿ mod 10^ 4  cyclic period 

                  2,500 -> 5^(  5-1 ) * 4 -> 2ⁿ mod 10^ 5  cyclic period 
                 12,500 -> 5^(  6-1 ) * 4 -> 2ⁿ mod 10^ 6  cyclic period 
                 62,500 -> 5^(  7-1 ) * 4 -> 2ⁿ mod 10^ 7  cyclic period 
                312,500 -> 5^(  8-1 ) * 4 -> 2ⁿ mod 10^ 8  cyclic period

              1,562,500 -> 5^(  9-1 ) * 4 -> 2ⁿ mod 10^ 9  cyclic period 
              7,812,500 -> 5^( 10-1 ) * 4 -> 2ⁿ mod 10^ 10 cyclic period 
             39,062,500 -> 5^( 11-1 ) * 4 -> 2ⁿ mod 10^ 11 cyclic period 
            195,312,500 -> 5^( 12-1 ) * 4 -> 2ⁿ mod 10^ 12 cyclic period 

            976,562,500 -> 5^( 13-1 ) * 4 -> 2ⁿ mod 10^ 13 cyclic period 
          4,882,812,500 -> 5^( 14-1 ) * 4 -> 2ⁿ mod 10^ 14 cyclic period 
         24,414,062,500 -> 5^( 15-1 ) * 4 -> 2ⁿ mod 10^ 15 cyclic period 
        122,070,312,500 -> 5^( 16-1 ) * 4 -> 2ⁿ mod 10^ 16 cyclic period

        610,351,562,500 -> 5^( 17-1 ) * 4 -> 2ⁿ mod 10^ 17 cyclic period 
      3,051,757,812,500 -> 5^( 18-1 ) * 4 -> 2ⁿ mod 10^ 18 cyclic period 
     15,258,789,062,500 -> 5^( 19-1 ) * 4 -> 2ⁿ mod 10^ 19 cyclic period 
     76,293,945,312,500 -> 5^( 20-1 ) * 4 -> 2ⁿ mod 10^ 20 cyclic period 

    381,469,726,562,500 -> 5^( 21-1 ) * 4 -> 2ⁿ mod 10^ 21 cyclic period 
  1,907,348,632,812,500 -> 5^( 22-1 ) * 4 -> 2ⁿ mod 10^ 22 cyclic period 
  9,536,743,164,062,500 -> 5^( 23-1 ) * 4 -> 2ⁿ mod 10^ 23 cyclic period 
 47,683,715,820,312,500 -> 5^( 24-1 ) * 4 -> 2ⁿ mod 10^ 24 cyclic period 

238,418,579,101,562,500 -> 5^( 25-1 ) * 4 -> 2ⁿ mod 10^ 25 cyclic period
```

Comment: By [Euler's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) $~\displaystyle 2^{\varphi\left(5^d\right)} \equiv 1 \pmod{5^d}.~$ Here, $\varphi(n)$ refers to the number of elements in $\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$ that are relatively prime to $n$.

$\varphi(5) = 4~$ and $~\varphi\left(5^d\right) = 4\times 5^{d-1}.~~$  Also, $~\displaystyle 2^{4\times 5^{(d-1)}} \equiv 0\pmod{2^d}.$

Comment: As an example of applying the last comment $~2^{20} \equiv 76 \pmod{100}~$ where $~\displaystyle 76 \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$ and $76 \equiv 1 \pmod{25}.$